# 3NF and many to many table mysql

Tags: mysql, 3nf, third-normal-form

As part of an assessment I need to build a site in PHP that relies on a database, the site can be on anything we want. The only restrictions on the site is the database must have a minumum of seven tables, must be in third normal form and have at minimum one many to many table.

Below is the Schema I have sofar, I am hoping people would be willing to tell me where it is not in third normal form, or if my many to many table (games) will not work.

I have an understanding of third normal form in that each item must be reliant on the primary key there to be no candidate key.

[image: database schema]

Thoughts?

Comment: The candidate key usually becomes the primary key.  The biggest thing that jumps out at me is that you aren't using surrogate keys (usually, auto-generated integer columns).  It would make changing some attributes (like the various names) much easier.  Oh, it's `**character_name**`.  What are you using `history` for?  What's with the other instances of `vault_number`?  That may be violating 3NF.  You also have a couple of unconnected tables.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse , The history is just a text feild that will hold information such as backstory. The history table will hold all the history of fallout major events. I'll look at removing the vault column also.